# Primefaces treetable implementation

Tags: primefaces, treetable

I am trying to implement primefaces treetable with checkbox and multiselection, like the one in [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf), everything works as expected but when I try to get the list of selected nodes, I only get the top nodes. So for example, if the user selects a child node of "Movies", it is not present in the TreeNode[] selectedNodes. Why is it behaving like this? What am I missing?
My codes are
In .xthml file

```
<p:treeTable value="#{backingBean.theTree}" var="tree" id="tree"  
     selection="#{backingBean.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="checkbox">  

    <p:column style="width:150px">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            Name  
        </f:facet>
        <span title="#{tree.objectCode}"><h:outputText value="#{tree.objectName}" /></span>
    </p:column>  

    <p:column style="width:150px">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            Object Description  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{tree.objectDescription}" />  
    </p:column> 

</p:treeTable>
```

Backingbean:

```
this.theTree = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);
TreeNode eachParent = new DefaultTreeNode(new Document(...some properties...), root);
```

And I have a recursive loop which basically creates more nodes in the same way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I only get the top nodes"? If you select a child of "Movie", will "Movie" be in selectedNodes?

Comment: yes but only "Movie" is present in the list, not is selected child

Comment: Could you paste your backingbean code?